# Angular 2 - Double level nested form - not initializing child of child

Tags: angular

I followed the tutorial [Nested Form](http://brophy.org/post/nested-reactive-forms-in-angular2/) on how to create a nested form for angular. I have forked their code and created a two level nested form.

Here are my goals:

1. Parent form (div with inputboxes)
2. Ability to Add multiple Child to Parent (div with inputboxes)
3. Ability to Add multiple Grandchild to the Child created above (div with inputboxes)

The Problem:
I cannot get the grandchild (child of child -infant) inputbox to show up after I clicked `Add Child`. The inputbox only shows up after I clicked, 'Add Infant'.
The input box appear there only during initialization. 
Please checkout my Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/O1iwys/

[image: no input box for infant]I believe that I have to initialize it here: (When I add the child)

```
   ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Initializing kid list', this.kid);
        this.childForm.addControl('kid', new FormArray([]));

    }
```

When I `Add Child` I do not see the input box for infants.

```
 addChild() {
        const child: ChildData = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            childField1: 'hello',
            childField2: '',
            childHiddenField1: '',
            kid: []
        };

        this.children.push(child);
        this.cd.detectChanges();
        return false;
    }
```

Please checkout my Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/O1iwys/

Comment: Well of course nothing renders, since `kid: []` is an empty array. The very first line is `<div *ngFor="let infant of kid; let idx=index ">`. There is a JSON dump at the bottom of the form. Just look at the difference between the instance data you are handing in and the state of the data when a field is present.

Comment: @NeilLunn I amended my code to  your suggestion `kid: [{id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) ,infantField: ' ' }]` but now I see a different error. Now I see `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:` I reproduced this on Plunker, please have a look: https://embed.plnkr.co/8VxK655nulNPVMofiAvU/  . Please inspect the console for the error too. Thank you!